# Change the Start menu icon of exe

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I have changed the icon of my application in Visual Studio but the default icon is still shown in the Start menu. How can I change the Start menu icon?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17490175/1017882

Comment: I already do it. if you look the link(it is image).

Comment: There's something wrong with your icon.  Hopefully "512" doesn't indicate the size of the icon :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you've just missed a part of it, here's my first suggestion:

1. Open your Windows Forms project in Visual Studio.
2. Open the main Form (probably Form1) in the Designer view.
3. Open the Properties Pane and go down until you see `Icon`, then click the Ellipses button and select your desired icon.
4. Go to the Project menu, click on appName Properties... (should be the last item in the menu)
5. In the Application panel to the right and at the bottom, there is a Default Icon section. Click the Ellipses to select your desired icon.
6. Save your changes and re-build. Then Publish the app. Does the correct "Default" icon appear in the Start Menu now?

If not:

You can write a custom shell extension to change the icon for this particular file on a file by file basis.

To do this though, you should write the extension in C++ (unmanaged code):

Refer to [How to change an icon for one single file of the specific type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046903/how-to-change-an-icon-for-one-single-file-of-the-specific-type) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for implementation specifics.

Comment: Can you please habe a look in Solution Explorer - double click the item named Resources under the Properties node. It should bring up a list of files you e added including icons. If you see a red x or red circle ontop of your icon then you need to remove the hyphen (-) from the icons filename then rename the file itself and all other references to that filename and then  save and rebuild.

Comment: Error: Cannot access a disposed object. Object Name:"FileCodeModel".

Comment: @OnePage also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813261/changing-apps-icon-works-in-title-bar-but-not-in-taskbar-or-start-menu?rq=1 - this person seems to have had the same issue and maybe one of those answers might help you.